# can i get the css value of a background image and load it as a background in an other div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

here is my problem :
i would like to click on a div with a specific background and display this specific background in another div.

i have built that code so far :

```
$( ".imag" ).each( function(i){

  $(this).attr('id','img'+i).on('click',function(){

   var bg = $(this).css('background-image').trim();
   var res = bg.substring(5, bg.length - 2);
   alert(res);  //return : file:///C:/Users/pierre/Desktop/blc(1)2/blc/10.jpg

   var reBg = "'url("+res+")'"
   alert(reBg )    // return :'url(file:///C:/Users/pierre/Desktop/blc(1)2/blc/10.jpg)'

  $( ".artisteImage" ).css({"background":reBg ,"background-size":"cover"}).promise().done(function(){alert (done)
});
 })

 });
```

Its not working but i don't know why .

If i try to do this code at the end, it work :

```
   $( ".artisteImage" ).css({"background":'url(10.jpg)',
"background-size":"cover"}).promise().done(function(){ //alert (done)
 });
```

I guess the problem is at the moment of building the variable reBg. Something with the strings?

thanks a lot,
Pierre

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lookup http://api.jquery.com/css/

what you need to do is similar to what is shown there

```
<script>
$( "div1" ).click(function() {
  var image = $( this ).css( "background-image" );
  $( "div2" ).attr("background-image", image)
});
</script>
```

you can also replace background-image for background-color if that is what you need to change

Comment: thanks a lot . it worked with       <script>
         $( "div1" ).click(function() {
         var image = $( this ).css( "background-image" );
         $( "div2" ).css("background-image", image)
       });
       </script>

Comment: the only problem is the background-position that's not working.

Comment: resolve by adding a callback with promise() :  $( ".artisteImage" ).css("background-image", image).promise().done(function(){  $( ".artisteImage" ).css("background-position","50 50"); });